# Update template without undoing all my edits?

Tags: templates

I want to edit a wordpress template to have a look and feel more like I want. With things like my flair on it.

After I change the template, does this mean I can no longer update it without reverting my changes?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into child themes - they allow you to customize your theme without overwriting the original files, meaning you can still take advantage of updates to the original theme.

[This tutorial on Themeshaper](http://themeshaper.com/2009/04/17/wordpress-child-theme-basics/) taught me a lot.

Comment: Yes Child themes are the way to go but sometimes some themes restrict themself and there child themes can't be used without editing them, but you will have to do those edits again, when you upgrade your parent theme. Better would be to point out to the theme author to make changes so that it can support. Although somewhat rare but I have come across it many times.